# How to not have the page refresh when my pop-up is closed?

Tags: javascript, popup, page-refresh

So I have a really simple pop-up on a page when a link is clicked, but it will refresh the page when I click on the close button. Which is bad since I have it within a set of Ajax tabs, so on refresh it goes back to tab1 instead of staying on tab3. Any idea's of a function to do this, I know there's one to make the parent page refresh, so there must be one for no refresh? Thanks!!

This is my JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // show popup when you click on the link
    $('.show-popup').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault(); // disable normal link function so that it doesn't refresh the page
        var docHeight = $(document).height();
        var docWidth = $(document).width(); //grab the height of the page
        $('.overlay-bg').show().css(); //display your popup and set height to the page height
        $('.overlay-content').css({'top': scrollTop+20+'px'}); //set the content 20px from the window top
    });

    // hide popup when user clicks on close button
    $('.close-btn').click(function(){
        $('.overlay-bg').hide(); // hide the overlay
    });

    // hides the popup if user clicks anywhere outside the container
    $('.overlay-bg').click(function(){
        $('.overlay-bg').hide();
    })
    // prevents the overlay from closing if user clicks inside the popup overlay
    $('.overlay-content').click(function(){
        return false;
    });
```

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing your close dom contains a link. In your close handler just add the event param and prevent default like you do for the other clicks.

See updated close function below

```
$('.close-btn').click(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    $('.overlay-bg').hide(); 
 });
```

Comment: Huh? Sorry I don't quite understand, I'm not good with JS. This is the close button link <a href="#" class="close-btn"><img src="images/closeBtn.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/closeBtn_hover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/closeBtn.png'"/></a>

Comment: I updated my answer with an example. Basically when you are using an a tag it is a link and unless you catch the click event and keep it from attempting to navigate to the href via the preventDefault function the browser will always reload.